# Transformer Line Driver: Avoiding Oscillation

Tags: operational-amplifier, driver, oscillation

## Summary:

First attempt oscillates, but is somewhat useable anyway.  Does the second attempt:

1. Actually fix the oscillation?
2. Present any other potential problems?

Both attempts are described below, with the questions repeated at the end.

---

---

## Details:

I want to send audio both ways between two rooms using a shielded twisted pair for each direction.  The last time I tried making my own system, it was a bit hacky and both lines insisted on oscillating, sometimes audibly.

---

Room A had this, with all through-hole parts on isolated perfboard/veroboard:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJBUlS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Room B had this, using [Jensen JT-11-FLCF](http://www.jensen-transformers.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/jt-11-flcf.pdf) transformers and an [Alesis 3630](http://www.alesis.com/products/view/3630-compressor) dual compressor:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fr97e4.png)</sup>

OutB and InA went to the local sound board.  The 3630's meters (both channels) and the sound board's meters never completely shut off until I unplugged the long cable run from the compressor, and I could sometimes hear a high-pitched drone in addition to the intended sound.  It sounded clean except for the annoying drone, which could be EQ'ed out at the receiving end, but of course that also affected the sound that I wanted as well.

---

This time around, I want to:

- Stop the oscillation
- Make both ends identical
- Incorporate the compressors directly into the driver circuitry to have one less bulky box

So, I'm thinking about using a [THAT4301 "Analog Engine"](http://www.thatcorp.com/4301_Analog_Engine_Dynamics_Processor.shtml), which includes a VCA, a true-RMS envelope follower, and a couple of opamps, to drive T1 from [this app note](http://www.jensen-transformers.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/as097.pdf).  Basically, it's one [Jensen JT-DB-E](http://www.jensen-transformers.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/jt-db-e.pdf) transformer used "normally" to drive the line and a second one used "backwards" to recover a line-level signal from it.

---

The new project is like this:

[image]

[image]

This would produce a line-level, isolated output at the receiving end.  Or for an additional listening station, I could just drop a standard mic input directly on the line without a transformer.

The big SMT pads are for C9, to change the "speed" range.  (attack and release times, for those familiar with dynamic range compressors)  The initial value of 10uF is from the datasheet.

Sorry to not have reference designators on the board; it was hard enough just to get all the values on and arranged somewhat sensibly.  I consider that to be more important in case the schematic and BOM disappear.  With a bit of study, you should be able to figure out which is what.

Power is from two 15VDC "wall-warts" wired in series to provide 15-0-15 as required by the 4301, and the entire board is meant to be foam-taped to the two transformers which themselves are foam-taped to a convenient flat spot near the local sound board.

---

## Questions:

1. Have I actually solved the oscillation problem?
2. Are there any other potential problems that I haven't addressed?

Comment: This question sadly lacks an overview circuit that explains how you can simultaneously send audio in one direction without it leaking back in the other.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean, @Andyaka.  I thought briefly about using a variation of the telephone hybrid arrangement, where multiple transmitters drive the same high-impedance line while each receiver subtracts its local transmitted signal from the common mix.  But I decided to use a dedicated line for each signal because it simplifies the transceivers and the extra wiring isn't all that much.